# NOT EXIST in PS QUERY

Tags: sql, oracle, peoplesoft

In Oracle's PeopleSoft ERP, the PeopleSoft Query tool (aka PS Query) is used to to generate SQL and run it through the web interface for users who do not have direct database access.

By using the not exist I am expecting that the values pulled from my query does not exist in my sub query since that's how it supposed to work.

But when I run my main query I get the values: '0290', '0477' and '0770' which when checking on the record of my sub query, it exists there as well. I have already checked the keys on all involved tables and I think I have included them in the criteria.

```
SELECT A.ADMIT_TERM FROM PS_ACAD_PROG A, PS_STDNT_AWD_PR_VW B
WHERE ( A.EFFDT = 
    (SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_ACAD_PROG A_ED 
    WHERE A.EMPLID = A_ED.EMPLID 
      AND A.ACAD_CAREER = A_ED.ACAD_CAREER 
      AND A.STDNT_CAR_NBR = A_ED.STDNT_CAR_NBR 
      AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SYSDATE) 
AND A.EFFSEQ = 
    (SELECT MAX(A_ES.EFFSEQ) FROM PS_ACAD_PROG A_ES 
    WHERE A.EMPLID = A_ES.EMPLID 
      AND A.ACAD_CAREER = A_ES.ACAD_CAREER 
      AND A.STDNT_CAR_NBR = A_ES.STDNT_CAR_NBR 
      AND A.EFFDT = A_ES.EFFDT) 
 AND A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID 
 AND A.ACAD_CAREER = B.ACAD_CAREER 
 AND B.INSTITUTION = A.INSTITUTION
 AND B.STRM = A.ADMIT_TERM 
 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT D.STRM 
 FROM PS_STDNT_CAR_TERM D 
 WHERE D.EMPLID = A.EMPLID 
 AND D.ACAD_CAREER = A.ACAD_CAREER 
 AND D.INSTITUTION = A.INSTITUTION 
 AND D.STDNT_CAR_NBR = A.STDNT_CAR_NBR
 AND D.STRM = A.ADMIT_TERM));
```

Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: The syntax looks OK. A working test case would help a lot. What's a PS Query?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Perhaps because those ADMIT_TERM's indeed don't exist for those STDNT_CAR_NBR?  Btw, do you really need to use that outdated method to link the tables? Just go with the times and use [the proper JOIN syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Comment: @LukStorms, I don't exacltly get what you mean about the proper JOIN syntax.

Comment: @Link there's a link in my comment you can click on.  Also, [this old SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2823039/4003419) explains why.

Comment: @Link do you want to pull students that have accepted an award on their admit term, but doesnt have a term activation record, is that what you want?